# the counter "c" is incremented in for loop without being initialized by 1

Tags: c

Please can someone help me to understand why the counter `c` is being incremented in the for loop without first being initialised?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
  char s1[50];  
  char s2[50];      
  int i,c,j,l;  
  printf("enter first name: ");     
  scanf("%s",s1);   
  printf("enter last name: ");  
  scanf("%s",s2);       
  for(i=0;i<50&&s1[i]!='\0';)
  {
    i++;        
    c++;    
  }
  l=c-1;    
  for(j=0; j<50 && s2[j]!='\0'; j++)
  {
    s1[l]=s2[j];       
    l++;    
  }      
  for(i=0; s1[i]!='\0' && i<l; i++)
  {
    printf("%c",s1[i]); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider yourself *unlucky* if that worked. It is something called Undefined Behavior that happened. Anything could've been the results. BTW, you should indent your code and write it cleanly with ample spacing. Believe me, you'll be glad you did it later.

Comment: Read books and ask your teacher if you have one. An answer to this question will solve your temporary problem not cure it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard (ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.79->10) says:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

Some compilers may initialize them to zero, though you can't expect the same behavior for all the compilers.

However, I see that question is **why is the counter “c” is incremented?**

The fact that you haven't initialized a variable doesn't stop `C` from incrementing it. However, re-iterating the above point, the starting value is indeterminate.

To conclude, your programme has ambiguous behavior

To get the expected results change the statement

```
int i,c,j,l;
```

to

```
int i,c=0,j,l; // c is initialized to zero, all others are at some point in the  pgm
```

Comment: thank youso my code is not correct i should initialize